# Conditions for inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-computation, quantum-information

[Matrix inverse and its properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BTWK.png)
The matrix M = ∑piσi ⊗ σi∗ where pi is probability and σi is Pauli matrix
has an inverse(its determinant det M is not equal to 0), i.e. the
following three conditions must hold simultaneously,
(i)q1:= p0 + p1 − p2 − p3 6= 0,
(ii) q2 := p0 − p1 + p2 −
p3 6= 0,
(iii)  q3 := p0 − p1 − p2 + p3 6= 0
How are q1, q2, q3 derived?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I answered your question, but in future you will get better answers from the community if you ask your questions better. Make sure to clearly define all of the terms and symbols you use in case someone is not familiar with the terminology. Also state what things you've tried and what specifically you do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix you are interested in is
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
p_0+p_3 & 0 & 0 & p_1+p_2\\
0 & p_0-p_3 & p_1 - p_2 & 0\\
0 & p_1 - p_2 & p_0-p_3 & 0\\
p_1+p_2 & 0 & 0 & p_0+p_3
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Compute the determinant. When is it equal to zero?